# Is DBContext added automatically with EF 6 or must it be added manuall?

Tags: entity-framework

New to EF. Following along with DBContext by Lerman/Miller.

When I start a new project, adding EF6 (Database First), the DBContext seems to be added as a default (ie I don't have to add the DBContext separately with T4). Also, for Lazy Loading, the "virtual" needed in the class definitions also seems to be there by default (I don't have to add it like in the book). Is this what is expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Database First` approach and use `EF x DbContext Generator` it creates the `DbContext` for you automatically and set the navigation properties, `virtual`. If you want to disable `lazy loading` you can simply use following code

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public MyContext()
   {
       this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the books you are reading are for code first development. If you use database first(especially with the designer) you don't need to make changes.